# React Ref ScrollTop always return 0

Tags: reactjs, next.js

here a sample code of my problem.

```js
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.btnDownload = React.createRef()
    this.showBanner = this.showBanner.bind(this)
  }
  
  showBanner(e){
    console.log(this.btnDownload.current.scrollTop)
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    window.addEventListener('scroll',this.showBanner);
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div ref={this.btnDownload} id="app"></div>
        <div id="body"></div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
#app {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
}

#body {
  height:1000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

why my btnDownload.current.scrollTop always return 0. I want to get a value when btnDownload element hit top of the browser or when the element out of windows browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `scrollTop` property is how far the element's content is scrolled.

See the docs here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop

This is why you always get 0.

Instead, you can get the bounding rect of the element and then compare it to the window:

```
showBanner(e) {
  const rect = this.btnDownload.current.getBoundingClientRect()

  const isInView = rect.top < window.innerHeight
  const isAtTop = rect.top <= 0

  console.log('Is in view:', isInView)
  console.log('Is at top:', isAtTop)
}
```

Hope this helps.